# FedEx International Shipping not displaying on magento checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping, fedex

I had been trying to implement FedEx in magento 1.9. I've inserted the credentials correctly, but still the shipping method is not displaying on checkout.

It works on shopping cart when I click on get quote for all the selected countries. 
[image: shopping cart]

And in checkout page in works for UAE only, and my country of origin is UAE.

But anything other than UAE it wont work on checkout.

Please help in letting me know if its issue in magento settings or through FedEx.

I've attached snapshot of my settings

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. share the solution if you have please?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the Status of "Ship to Applicable Countries" from

`"Specific Countries" to "All Allowed Countries"`.

Surely It will work for other Countries than UAE and on Check Out.

Comment: still not working, is any other way available?